# How to set delay

Tags: javascript

I have this line of code:

```
document.querySelector(".theclass").outerHTML = "The outerHTML";
```

And it fires right when the page is loaded, however this causes the "Unable to set property of undefined or null reference" error. As I understand, this could happen because the `.theclass` is not there yet and therefor the script can't target it.

Is there a simple way, using JavaScript to simply set a delay for this line of code, but so it will continue fire automatically as it would did when the page is loaded?

Comment: Place you `script` as `last-child` of the `<body>`

Comment: You mean at the end of the document? Yes, tried this. `.theclass` appears a little bit after the page is loaded(it loads asynchronously)

Comment: Use a MutationObserver to see when the element is loaded and then update the content

Comment: Is there any know parent element which is present on page load

Comment: like https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ky1nr1dj/1/

Comment: Arun! That's awesome! I didn't know about something like this. Very interesting, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
document.onload=function(){
   document.querySelector(".theclass").outerHTML = "The outerHTML";
};
```

**EDIT:** for async loading, you could use jQUery

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('.theclass')) {
       document.querySelector(".theclass").outerHTML = "The outerHTML";
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried this. `.theclass` appears a little bit after the page is loaded(it loads asynchronously)

Answer (score 0):

One option is use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to listener for element additions and when our target element is added we can update it and remove the observer

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('parentelement').innerHTML = '<span class="theclass">theclass</span>';
}, 500);

// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#parentelement');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type, mutation);
    Array.from(mutation.addedNodes).forEach(function(el) {
      if (el.classList.contains('theclass')) {
        el.outerHTML = "The outerHTML";
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    });
  });
});

var config = {
  childList: true
};
observer.observe(target, config);
```

```html
<div id="parentelement"></div>
```